# Перенаправление страниц сайта одного домена

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect

есть страница site.com/?theme=mm, хотелось бы, чтобы при заходе на неё пользователь автоматом перенаправлялся на главную страницу site.com
подскажите пожалуста как это грамотно сделать - хотелось бы через .htaccess
(cms drupal 7)
пробовал по примеру Redirect /page-1.html /page-2.html (взято с https://yutex.ru/redirect/kak-sdelat-redirect-vse-vidi.html), т.е.
Redirect /?theme=mm /index.php
но ничего не вышло (строка вставлялась в самое начало файла)

Answer (score 0):

Это функционал самого сайта, а не конфигурация сервера, не нужно выносить этот функционал в файл .htaccess

Для этих целей есть [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect)

Еще такое можно сделать многими способами, например можно переопределить данный путь и просто направить его на новый адрес таким способом

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function NAME_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['your_path'] = array(
    'title' => t('Edit example'),
    'description' => t('Example of edit'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('new_your_path'),
  );
}
```

Comment: спасибо! а вручную нельзя нигде прописать? не хотелось бы модуль лишний ставить..

Comment: можно многими способами, на счет проблем производительности и то что они связаны с количеством модулей это неправда. Проблема в друпале которая влияет на производительность это структура базы данных, она очень универсальна, но каждое поле это отдельная таблица и запросов очень много и они большые. Хотя если грамотно настроить кеширование тогда все будет хорошо